# How do EIP numbers get assigned?

Tags: eip

I've read the the [EIPs](https://eips.ethereum.org/) home page and [EIP-1](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1) but I'm still not 100% sure how EIP numbers get assigned.

EIP-1 says this:

> Once the EIP is ready for the repository, the EIP editor will:
>
> - Assign an EIP number (generally the PR number, but the decision is with the editors)
> - ...

So am I correct to assume that is up to the *EIP editors*, who oftentimes are different from the *EIP authors*, to assign a number to an EIP?

If yes, and they do not want to use the PR or the issue number, is it common practice to increment the number used in the last EIP, or do they sometimes skip some values for brevity reasons (e.g. EIP-5500 is easier to remember than EIP-5497)?

Here's why I find this confusing. There currently exist two proposals in which the authors seem to have assigned whatever numbers they wanted:

- [EIP-5555](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/5046)
- [EIP-9000](https://ethereum-magicians.org/t/eip-9000-layer3-scaling-standard/9039)

This is in spite of the fact that the latest PR number on GitHub is 5045:

[image: GitHub EIPs repo]

My guess is that these proposals haven't been vetted yet by EIPs editors - but I want to make sure that my guess is correct.

Comment: I've understood they try to prevent 'number squatting', so all EIPs should have a "random" number. Don't have a source for this, though. Otherwise don't really know

Comment: It doesn't look like the author behind [EIP-9000](https://ethereum-magicians.org/t/eip-9000-layer3-scaling-standard/9039) cared much about number squatting.